# IBM DB2 - Can't Set Schema

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to use the command, SET SCHEMA. However, it does not appear to be working, I get an error message. I am able to use the schema if I use Schema.Tablename, but this can be tedious. I am perfectly connected to the database and all the schema properties appear in my schemas folder.

The error message is below:

------------------------------ Commands Entered ------------------------------

```
SET SCHEMA RSBALANCE;
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET SCHEMA RSBALANCE
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0805N  Package "NULLID.SQLC2H20 0X41414141415A425A" was not found.  
SQLSTATE=51002

SQL0805N  Package "NULLID.SQLC2H20 0X41414141415A425A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my machine was missing an update from IBM. This allowed me to use the command from bhamby to work properly.

Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for DB2 is ([Info Center link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001016.html)):

```
SET SCHEMA = 'YOUR_SCHEMA'
```

If you're using the Command Line Processor (which it appears you are by the error message), you have to use double-quotes (it does matter!):

```
SET SCHEMA = "YOUR_SCHEMA"
```

Comment: I'm using the Control Center Command Editor. For some reason, my queries work sometimes. I'm trying to figure that out since my set schema isn't working and yet it will still display rows.

Comment: Actually, quotes are optional. Because the schema is an identifier, you can treat it like a table name or stored procedure name.

Comment: While I am in the IBM DB2 Control Center, I'm able to see all my schemas, etc. But when I try the following statement of: 

SELECT PKGSCHEMA, PKGNAME,
       PKGVERSION, UNIQUE_ID
FROM SYSCAT.PACKAGES

None of the schemas pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Information Center has documentation on the [SQL0805N error](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00805n.html).

This is the relevant course of action:

> If the DB2 utility programs need to be rebound to the database, the
>   database administrator can accomplish this by issuing one of the
>   following CLP command from the bnd subdirectory of the instance, while
>   connected to the database:
>
> For the DB2 utilities:
>
> ```
> db2 bind @db2ubind.lst blocking all grant public
> ```
>
> For CLI::
>
> ```
> db2 bind @db2cli.lst blocking all grant public
> ```

Comment: I tried both commands, however it states that the db2ubind.lst and db2cli.lst could not be found.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's a problem with my client. My co-workers log on with the same user and they're able to use the commands perfectly. It is only on my machine and setup that I can't use the schema commands. 

In addition, when I try to view all the schema records on my machine, it does not return any of the rows in the editor. However I can still view these tables in the control center.

Comment: Were you in the bnd directory? I think it might be under /home/db2inst1/sqllib/bnd on Linux.